# Understand WorkManager's WorkSpec table

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I have been using workManager in my app. I have seen that it creates a database with one of the table called workSpec. I have all the workers information is stored in it. I would like to understand about the columns of the table like what state, run attempt count, period_start_time etc.

**NOTE :**

- WorkManager Version : 1.0.1
- device is always connected to the charge source hence there no chance
  of going it into doze.

[image]

Other questions I have :

- How can I reduce the size of the database as I have seen it is growing like crazy and the old unused items are not removed.
- In the same worker shown in the image, it was scheduled with periodicRequest which is to run every 1 hour but it has run only once and never came again. Why?

code for periodic requests

```
 public WorkRequest createWorkRequest(int interval, String tagName) {
    if (tagName.endsWith(Task.TAG_SUFFIX)) {
        return new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(CommonWorker.class, interval, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .addTag(tagName)
                .build();
    }

    return new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(CommonWorker.class)
            .setInitialDelay(interval, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addTag(tagName)
            .build();
}
```

And

```
 private void triggerSchedulerFor(int interval, String tagName) {
    WorkRequest workRequest = zdsWorkRequest.createWorkRequest(interval, tagName);
    Operation operation;
    if (tagName.endsWith(Task.TAG_SUFFIX)) {
        operation = workManager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(tagName,
                ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE,
                (PeriodicWorkRequest) workRequest);

    } else {
        operation = workManager.enqueueUniqueWork(tagName, ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE,
                (OneTimeWorkRequest) workRequest);

    }
    Log.i(TAG, "State for Tag = " + tagName + "  is = " + operation.getState().getValue());
}
```

- There was another worker has to run every 15 mins periodically but I have seen a pattern that it triggers exactly every 15 mins but after every 1 hour the 15 mins worker triggers with delay of 11min i.e below is log trace

> Line 2614: 05-30 09:41:28.876 17609 17609 I TaskPlannerImpl:
>   onTaskTimerElapsed 900_SEC    Line 6359: 05-30 09:56:28.907 17609 17609
>   I TaskPlannerImpl: onTaskTimerElapsed 900_SEC     Line 9081: 05-30
>   10:11:52.355 17609 17609 I TaskPlannerImpl: onTaskTimerElapsed 900_SEC
>     Line 12991: 05-30 10:26:28.901 17609 17609 I TaskPlannerImpl:
>   onTaskTimerElapsed 900_SEC    Line 17115: 05-30 10:50:03.389 17609 17609
>   I TaskPlannerImpl: onTaskTimerElapsed 900_SEC     Line 18727: 05-30
>   10:56:28.881 17609 17609 I TaskPlannerImpl: onTaskTimerElapsed 900_SEC
>     Line 20945: 05-30 11:11:28.907 17609 17609 I TaskPlannerImpl:
>   onTaskTimerElapsed 900_SEC    Line 23068: 05-30 11:26:28.909 17609 17609
>   I TaskPlannerImpl: onTaskTimerElapsed 900_SEC     Line 26932: 05-30
>   11:52:40.685 17609 17609 I TaskPlannerImpl: onTaskTimerElapsed 900_SEC
>     Line 27598: 05-30 11:56:28.903 17609 17609 I TaskPlannerImpl:
>   onTaskTimerElapsed 900_SEC    Line 29724: 05-30 12:11:28.896 17609 17609
>   I TaskPlannerImpl: onTaskTimerElapsed 900_SEC     Line 31790: 05-30
>   12:26:28.902 17609 17609 I TaskPlannerImpl: onTaskTimerElapsed 900_SEC
>     Line 34414: 05-30 12:46:14.844 17609 17609 I TaskPlannerImpl:
>   onTaskTimerElapsed 900_SEC    Line 36131: 05-30 12:56:28.902 17609 17609
>   I TaskPlannerImpl: onTaskTimerElapsed 900_SEC     Line 38692: 05-30
>   13:11:28.881 17609 17609 I TaskPlannerImpl: onTaskTimerElapsed 900_SEC
>     Line 41469: 05-30 13:26:28.902 17609 17609 I TaskPlannerImpl:
>   onTaskTimerElapsed 900_SEC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the workSpec table format, this is obviously an implementation details that may change in the future. I would avoid to make any changes directly to it or to assume that some particular information is stored in a particular format.

What it's currently stored there can be seen from [`WorkSpec` source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/work/workmanager/src/main/java/androidx/work/impl/model/WorkSpec.java). Some of these information are accessible through WorkManager's API. As an example, you can access the attempt count both inside your Worker ([`ListenableWorker#getRunAttemptCount()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ListenableWorker#getRunAttemptCount())) and through `WorkInfo` (WorkManager v2.1.0-alpha01 added [`WorkInfo#getRunAttemptCount()'](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkInfo#getRunAttemptCount()).

But again, you should never do any changes directly to WorkManager's tables or rely on its particular format.

For your other questions:

### Reduce WorkManager's DB size

When you create your WorkRequest, you can specify for how long you need to keep this workRequest in the DB using [`keepResultsForAtLeast()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/work/WorkRequest.Builder#keepresultsforatleast). Keep in mind that once the WorkRequest is pruned from the DB you cannot get any more information on it.
Another, more drastic and dangerous, option is to use [`WorkManager#pruneWork()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/work/WorkManager#prunework). In this case WorkManager prunes from the DB all the finished work. Again, after this operation it's not possible anymore to access the WorkRequest's `WorkInfo`.

### PeriodicWorker non repeated

Would be useful to see how you create the WorkRequest and the Worker code, on which device/OS have you seen this behavior and which WorkManager version are you using.

### Non precise interval for PeriodicWorker

WorkManager tries to respect the WorkRequest parameters compatibly with the Android OS battery optimization strategies (mainly Doze mode). This may result in the Worker being shifted in the nearest [maintenance window](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have edited the question with more info.
I wanted to know about the column details as i wanted to know what is status of my periodic request. I checked the code from the https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/work/workmanager/src/main/java/androidx/work/impl/model/WorkSpec.java and found that it's state is succeed (as in the table state is 2)

What can be carried out from this?

Comment: If you want to know the status of a WorkRequest you should access it's WorkInfo. Regarding Periodic Worker status. BTW, Periodic Work is not supposed to go to a succeeded status but it should transition back to Enqueued when it returns Success: https://twitter.com/pfmaggi/status/1134548259425443841

Comment: Cool! I will check upon why if that is request was triggered as Periodic or Onetime. What do you say about my last question. The device was always connected to charge(which means not in doze) but still those 15mins PeriodicRequest delayed by 11 mins if you could see in the logtrace.